# How can put split integers in a two-dimensional array?

Tags: vb.net

I making matrix calculator. so, `Textbox_A` contains `vbCrLf` and tries to put it in `Array_A`.
and I would like to put Array_A in Result Matrix.
It's like

Textbox_a:

(1 2 3)

(4 5 6)

[Matrix to Array]

Array_a(0)(0) = 1

Array_a(0)(1) = 2

Array_a(0)(2) = 3

Array_a(1)(0) = 4

...

I have done string splits through several articles, but changing them to integers causes many problems.
[This picture is Matrix_A and result Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5rPY.png)

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? [If your question doesn't include code, are you sure it shouldn't?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/8967612)

Comment: Firstly, your title says "two-dimensional array" but your code shows a jagged array. Do you know the difference? If not, you should learn. Once you understand, you need to specify clearly what you actually want in your question.

Comment: Also, you need to put some thought into the problem and determine exactly where the issue is. Getting data out of a `TextBox` and getting data into an array are two different things. Which one are you actually having trouble with? If it's both then you should be asking two separate questions, each containing all and only the information relevant to that specific issue. One of the main reasons that beginners have trouble solving problems is that they don't make enough effort to determine where the actual problem is. Learning to do that is the first step.

Comment: @jmcihinney Thank you for pointing it out. I'll look for more as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if the size of your initial matrix, formatted as text, is fixed, but here is some code to help you get started. The code tries to calculate the number of columns and rows.

The actual code is in the `TextToArray` function, that takes as input as string formatted as you described:
(1 2 3) (cr/lf)
(4 5 6)
and outputs a two dimensional array. The `Main` sub is just used to call `TextToArray` and display results.

So, in your example, you should pass `TextBox_A.Text` to `TextToArray`

There is minimal error checking here - you should add more to validate that data entered are numbers (check the `Integer.TryParse` function) and that the number of columns is the same across lines.

```
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim myInput As String = "(1 2 3)" & vbCrLf & "(4 5 6)"
        Dim ret As Integer(,) = TextToArray(myInput)
        If ret IsNot Nothing Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To ret.GetUpperBound(0) - 1
                For n As Integer = 0 To ret.GetUpperBound(1) - 1
                    Console.WriteLine(i & "," & n & "=" & ret(i, n))
                Next
            Next
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("No results - wrong input format")
        End If
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Private Function TextToArray(matrix As String) As Integer(,)
        Dim noOfRows As Integer = matrix.Split(vbCrLf).Count
        Dim noOfColumns As Integer = 0
        If noOfRows > 0 Then
            noOfColumns = matrix.Split(vbCrLf)(0).Split(" ").Count
        End If
        If noOfColumns > 0 And noOfRows > 0 Then
            Dim ret(noOfRows, noOfColumns) As Integer
            Dim lines As String() = matrix.Split(vbCrLf)
            Dim row As Integer = 0
            For Each line As String In lines
                Dim col As Integer = 0
                line = line.Replace("(", "")
                line = line.Replace(")", "")
                For Each s As String In line.Split(" ")
                    ret(row, col) = Integer.Parse(s)
                    col += 1
                Next
                row += 1
            Next
            Return ret
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Function
```

This outputs:

```
0,0=1
0,1=2
0,2=3
1,0=4
1,1=5
1,2=6
```

Comment: You should have Option Strict On for this code and all the time. This will not compile with Option Strict On.

Comment: Wow... Thanks very much. The error that appears when you keep pressing the function button was solved by raising the variable to the top of sub.

Comment: I also put in a calculation function, but it works!